# Swagger codegen option to change casing in TypeScript

Tags: c#, node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

We are using swagger codegen to generate a TypeScript client.
Its working fine but when it generates the objects it converting our pascal casing into camel casing and failing as it doesnt match the JSON object casing getting returned form the web server.

Note: we are using a C# WebAPIv2 project, hence the pascal casing.

We use the online API for generating

http://generator.swagger.io/#!/clients/generateClient

Have noticed the options property but cannot find any documentation on it.

```
{
"spec": {},
"options": {},
"swaggerUrl": "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
"securityDefinition": {
  "type": "string",
  "description": "string"
}
}
```

Is there a configuration option to change this? or can someone point me to any documentation on the option property?

Thanks,

Joel

Comment: I'm working on project NSwag which generates correct cased TypeScript (from JsonProperty attribute). You should have a look: http://nswag.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue in the GitHub source code and proposed a solution, someone posted back with a workaround, however i think we were going about it the wrong way

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1926

I think the best approach for language compatibility is to:

- Write Web API C# in Pascal casing
- Covert using an action filter to camel case Json output (http://fizzylogic.nl/2014/07/30/changing-the-casing-of-json-properties-in-asp-dot-net-web-api/)
- Creating the client with TyepScript default option will then work
- Creating the C# client will add the JsonProperty to translate from camel to - - pascal and resulting C# client will be pascal cased

Regards,
Joel

Answer (score 0):

The NSwag project (https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag) is a toolchain that handles the generation of swagger specifications, TypeScript and clients either from .NET assemblies or from a Swagger specification. It allows you to import your swagger JSON specification and generate TypeScripts from it, keeping the right case for your properties.